# Accessing a TextFile in binary mode

Tags: delphi

I have LARGE text file (doesn't fit in memory) that contains 'records'. One record consists in 4 text lines. However, sometimes these lines are too long and are split. So, a record ca have more than 4 lines.

Clarification: Please note that the 'records' are not real records. Are lines of text. I don't know how long is each line and (as already explained) neither if there are 4 or more lines in a 'record'.
A record can be like this:

```
@ human text text text text text      <------ always starts with @
AGCTACGTAGCTACGTAGCTACGCTACGT
+ text text text text text            <------ always starts with +
A!B@CDEF+$DG++DAG@                    <------ unfortunately @ and + can also appear (randomly) in this row.
```

Initially I need to read records from that file one by one, sequentially. This is easy. But later I need random access to records, based on the address of that record in file.
Example: GetRecord(IOAddress: Cardinal)

So, I was thinking in creating a matrix of Cardinals (or Int64) and storing in it the address where every record starts.

Unfortunately, TextFile does not have a Position property (as in TFileStream.Position or Seek).
Any idea how can easily achieve something like this?

---

Comment: Read it as binary all the way

Comment: @DavidHeffernan- Hi David. Yeah.... I know. That's the obvious solution. But then I have to write all that parsing code plus some kind of rudimentary buffering mechanism. I was hoping (big hope, I know) that there is some way to force the TextFile to read from a specific address in file.

Comment: Why a buffering mechanism and why a parser? Simply load a record as binary. If they are different sized, then use pointers to records and GetMem to get memory for each of them. How do you know the size?

Comment: Buffering is easy. There are plenty of good classes around to do that. Parsing doesn't seem too hard either. And what about something like `TStreamReader`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-Yes, Tstreamreader is what I am going to use. Anyway, my hope was that there is already a Delphi class that gives text-mode access to a file but also with Seek/Position support.